# Does a polynomial solution to weakly-NP Complete problem mean P = NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, subset-sum

Suppose someone finds a polynomial solution to weakly-NP Complete problem does that mean P = NP.

Answer (score 3):

All weakly NP-complete problems are NP-complete by definition,
so yes, a polynomial time algorithm would imply P = NP.